Is there a good way to run selenium tests on a Linux machine against a WebKit browser?
I asked this question on SQA a few days ago but got no response.  I know this is more open-ended, so I appreciate some leeway.
A majority of our users are on mobile safari, but we run our automation in gitlab pipelines using a linux kernal as the runner.  Is there a way a good option for running our tests in webkit-based browser to ensure it renders correctly on Safari (or as best we can)? My googling found webkitgtk, and I did find some driver documentation on it, but I don't know anything about it AT ALL, other than it exists. I'm hoping there us another option that I am unfamiliar with.

Technically all browsers support "webkit".  It's just called "blink" on non-apple browsers.  Still it sounds like you want true device testing and using something like Appium might be best.  You can also use "SafariDriver" for testing desktop and mobile versions of Safari.  See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-developer-tools/webdriver

Well, you're right in the sense that blink was forked from webkit, but that was 10 years ago - the two engines have diverged quite substantially since then.  In fact, they also both use two different javascript engines (one developed by apple and the other by Google).  So, there's enough differences where I would like to be able to run more tests on webkit than blink.
I was really hoping that there was a selenium-controllable browser that uses webkit and able to run cross-platform on Mac and Linux (to make test development easy).  Not sure if that exists though.

I guess PhantomJS would be your only option there.  Didn't realize that there is no Linux version of Safari.  Not sure if Phantom is still developed?

me neither.  I remember that from back in the day.  Is it webkit based?

Yup, deprecated. in 2018: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344
